# toLocalIterator seems empty after using it

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Why is that after mapping each partition of a Spark DataFrame to a Pandas Dataframe, I can only loop on its partitions once?

For example, I will have output for this

```
columns = sdf.schema.fieldNames()
parts = sdf.repartition(2).rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iterator: [pd.DataFrame(list(iterator), columns=columns)]).toLocalIterator()

for df in parts:
  print(df.shape)
```

But the next time I run the loop:

```
for df in parts:
  print(df.shape)
```

there will be virtually no computation time or output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toLocalIterator()` returns Scala `Iterator` (via python's Java gateway).

In Scala, [`Iterator`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html) trait extends `TraversableOnce`. As name suggests, it can only be  iterated through one time (and only by using `next()` method).

> A call to `it.next()` will return the next element of the iterator and
>   advance the state of the iterator. Calling `next` again on the same
>   iterator will then yield the element one beyond the one returned
>   previously. If there are no more elements to return, a call to `next` will throw a
>   `NoSuchElementException`.

If you need to iterate over the same collection twice, you probably can use `duplicate()`  to get two iterator instances traversable independently.